# Disable "Wrap text output on resize" from console screen buffer size settings programmatically (C)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, cmd, console

I cant figure out how to disable wrapping with C code using window.h

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you explored the Windows API [console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions)?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [SetConsoleMode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) and at the flags `ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT` and `DISABLE_NEWLINE_AUTO_RETURN`.

Comment: Good answer, but it does not solve the problem... text wrapping on resize will wrap lines even if in the buffer the text is not wrapped.

Comment: Ditto here, at least from Mingw. DISABLE_NEWLINE_AUTO_RETURN is no longer defined (and would not do the job in any case). ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT seems more like it, but has no effect. You can still see the checkbox checked in properties->layout.

Answer (score 0):

This is not c++-related problem. It is related to your command prompt. If you are a windows user, right-click on command-prompt's title and choose properties and follow the picture below.
[image]